# Binary Bomb Stage 2 Arithmetic

Tags: c, assembly, binary-bomb

I have been trying to figure out the values for this stage for days but I just can't seem to get it.

What I know is that there are 3 input values required: `%rsi, %rdx, %rcx.`
The values for `%rdx` and `%rcx` has to be equal.

Much help is greatly appreciated.

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_2:
=> 0x00000000004011dd <+0>:     sub    $0x8,%rsp
   0x00000000004011e1 <+4>:     cmp    $0x3,%rdi                      // %rdi = 3
   0x00000000004011e5 <+8>:     jne    0x401207 <phase_2+42>
   0x00000000004011e7 <+10>:    not    %rsi
   0x00000000004011ea <+13>:    or     %rsi,%rcx
   0x00000000004011ed <+16>:    xor    $0xfffffffffffffff2,%rcx       // -14, %rcx 
   0x00000000004011f1 <+20>:    add    $0x51,%rcx                     // 81, %rcx
   0x00000000004011f5 <+24>:    cmp    $0xfffffffffffffe53,%rcx       // -429, $rcx
   0x00000000004011fc <+31>:    sete   %al
   0x00000000004011ff <+34>:    movzbl %al,%eax
   0x0000000000401202 <+37>:    cmp    %rdx,%rcx                      // %rdx = %rcx 
   0x0000000000401205 <+40>:    je     0x401213 <phase_2+54>
   0x0000000000401207 <+42>:    callq  0x401af5 <bomb_blast>
   0x000000000040120c <+47>:    mov    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
   0x0000000000401213 <+54>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
   0x0000000000401217 <+58>:    retq
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent C code is:

```c
int64_t phase_2(int64_t rdi, int64_t rsi, int64_t rcx, int64_t rdx)
{
    if (rdi != 3)
    {
        bomb_blast();
        return -1;
    }
    rsi = !rsi;
    rcx |= rsi;
    rcx ^= 0xfffffffffffffff2;
    rcx += 0x51;
    if (rdx != rcx) {
        bomb_blast();
        return -1;
    }
    return (rcx == 0xfffffffffffffe53);
}
```

Assume the expected return value for this function is 1. (only in this way the value of `%rdx` is a constant number), as `rcx` equals to `rdx` at last, `rdx` should be 0xfffffffffffffe53(-429).

Then we need to do some inverse calculation to find out the value of `rcx`.

```
rcx + 0x51 = 0xfffffffffffffe53
rcx = 0xfffffffffffffe02
```

XOR's inverse operation is XOR itself. That is, if `a ^ b = c`, then `a = b ^ c` and `b = a ^ c`.

```
rcx ^ 0xfffffffffffffff2 = 0xfffffffffffffe02
rcx = 0xfffffffffffffe02 ^ 0xfffffffffffffff2
rcx = 0x1f0
```

As the value of `rsi` is defined by us, we can use the simplest situation `x | 0 = x`. So the value of `rcx` is 0x1f0(496) and `rsi` is -1.

Comment: Thank you so much for that detailed explanation !